# Is this thread safe list using lock is perfect?

Tags: c++, concurrency, thread-safety

Below is the example source code of thread safe list using lock from c++ concurrency in action 2nd.

```
template<typename T>
class threadsafe_list
{
    struct node
    {
        std::mutex m;
        std::shared_ptr<T> data;
        std::unique_ptr<node> next;
        node():
            next()
        {}
        node(T const& value):
            data(std::make_shared<T>(value))
        {}
    };
    node head;
public:
    threadsafe_list()
    {}
    ~threadsafe_list()
    {
        remove_if([](node const&){return true;});
    }
    threadsafe_list(threadsafe_list const& other)=delete;
    threadsafe_list& operator=(threadsafe_list const& other)=delete;
    void push_front(T const& value)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<node> new_node(new node(value));
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(head.m);
        new_node->next=std::move(head.next);
        head.next=std::move(new_node);
    }
    template<typename Function>
    void for_each(Function f)
    {
        node* current=&head;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(head.m);
        while(node* const next=current->next.get())
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> next_lk(next->m);
            lk.unlock();
            f(*next->data);
            current=next;
            lk=std::move(next_lk);
        }
    }
    template<typename Predicate>
    std::shared_ptr<T> find_first_if(Predicate p) // (1) is it safe ?
    {
        node* current=&head;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(head.m);
        while(node* const next=current->next.get())
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> next_lk(next->m);
            lk.unlock();
            if(p(*next->data))
            {
                return next->data;
            }
            current=next;
            lk=std::move(next_lk);
        }
        return std::shared_ptr<T>();
    }
    template<typename Predicate>
    void remove_if(Predicate p)
    {
        node* current=&head;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(head.m);
        while(node* const next=current->next.get())
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> next_lk(next->m);
            if(p(*next->data)) 
            {
                std::unique_ptr<node> old_next=std::move(current->next);
                current->next=std::move(next->next);
                next_lk.unlock();
            }
            else
            {
                lk.unlock();
                current=next;
                lk=std::move(next_lk);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I understand how this code works.
But I don't think this code is perfect.
I put marks on the place to argue with.

(1) find_first_if returns shared_ptr instead of copied value of T. It gives chance of concurrency issue. I'll explain more.
If user get the shared_ptr of data using find_first_if, then user can access the data through this pointer even while node is being modified. Is this safe action? I don't think so.
My suggestion is that it should return copied value of T, which results in T find_first_if(Predicate p) {...}. Am I correct?

Edit :
I separated the other questions from original one and create another post to focus on one subject

Comment: just my opinion, but the container probably should not care about that. If it's unsafe to access the content, the caller should wrap it in atomic wrapper.

Comment: let's say, I'd prefer return a `T&`.

Comment: or maybe an `Iterator` type (not in the provided code), which used by `std::find_first_of`

Comment: @appleapple If you return T&, There is no difference with the case share_ptr, because reference can access to the data in node directly. This example is from very famous book by a well-known author, so I'm trying to find what I am missing.

Comment: @ myoldgrandpa I simply mean the same as you, there is no reason return a `shared_ptr` here.

Comment: if the client want a `shared_ptr`, they do that theirself

Comment: for the authoritative, well, if the `Predicate` (in destructor) can be wrong, I suspect the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is actually necessary, not to prevent leaks but stack overflow. Because the nodes own each other, the destructor of each will recursively call destructors of all the following nodes. So destructing a long list would easily blow up the stack.
2. Yes, that is incorrect, you should consult the documentation for `Predicate`. Even better would be to use C++14 `[](const auto&){return true;}` but due to lack of `make_unique`, the code might have been written with C++11 only.
3. Yes, the exposed `data` is not protected by any lock anymore. Copy might be expensive and what about move-only types? Again, this should be properly documented in the method.